# Matlab: Arrayfun with Matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am trying to rewrite the following code using `arrayfun`

```
A = ones(3,3,3)
for i = 1:3
    B(i) = trace(A(:,:,i));
end
```

I hopefully tried

```
f = @(x) trace(x)
B = arrayfun(f, A);
```

But this just (as you would expect) traces over each individual `A(i,j,k)` not the `A(:,:,i)` as I would like. I then tried declaring `A{i}=ones(3,3)` as a cell and passing to `arrayfun` but this didn't work either.

How can I vectorise functions on matrices in Matlab?

Comment: Curious if either of the solutions provided here work for you?

Comment: Hi Divikar, the solutions do work but neither one gives me a general way to vectorise functions of matrices on a GPU that I can test ... yet. Unfortunately the server I have access to is running a Matlab version without `pagefun` but is being upgraded on Thursday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bsxfun` based vectorized solution that ab(uses) how `trace` is defined - `sum of diagonal elements` -

```
%// Get size of A
[m,n,r] = size(A) 

%// Get indices of the diagonal elements for each 3D "slice" as columns of idx
idx = bsxfun(@plus,[1:m+1:m*n]',[0:r-1]*m*n) %//'

%// Thus, for your 3 x 3 x 3 case, idx would be -
%//idx =
%//      1    10    19
%//      5    14    23
%//      9    18    27
%// and these are the linear indices to the diagonal elements to each `3D` slide.

%//Index into A with idx and sum along columns to get each element of desired output
B = sum(A(idx),1)
```

If you would like to save on workspace cluttering with not-so-necessary extra variables, avoid `idx` with -

```
B = sum(A(bsxfun(@plus,[1:m+1:m*n]',[0:r-1]*m*n)),1)
```

---

**For working with GPUs**

If you have to work with `GPUs`, you can declare them as gpuArrays with `gpuArray(A)`, then subsequent work involving `A` would be done on GPU and you would get the output as a gpuArray, which you can get back as a CPU variable with `gather(..)`.

Thus, a complete code would look like this -

```
[m,n,r] = size(A); %// Get size
gpu_A = gpuArray(A); %// copy data from CPU to GPU

%// Perform calculations on GPU
gpu_B = sum(gpu_A(bsxfun(@plus,[1:m+1:m*n]',[0:r-1]*m*n)),1); %//'

B = gather(gpu_B); %// get back output onto CPU
```

**Quick tests:** With GTX 750 Ti (that I have access to), this appears to give me a 3x speedup over your loopy code.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to use `arrayfun` you could try a trick like this:

```
arrayfun(@(i)trace(A(:,:,i)), 1:size(A,3))
```

but note that `arrayfun` is **NOT VECTORIZATION**!!, it's just a wrapper for a loop and often is slower than a loop due to added overhead.

While equally not vectorization, to do it your second way you should have just changed to `cellfun`. i.e. if `A{i} = ones(3,3)` then

```
cellfun(@(x)trace(x), A)
```

Comment: I wanted to use `arrayfun` as I am running the code on a GPU. Am I correct in thinking that the `arrayfun` wrapper will speed up my calculation in this case?

Comment: @rwolst Think `pagefun` is the equivalent of `araryfun` for GPUs. Still, please make sure of that by looking at the official documentation for that.

Comment: @Divakar: No, `arrayfun` is a good way of pushing a loop onto the GPU. Of course, the usual caveats regarding parallelization overhead apply.

Comment: @Jonas That's good to know. Is this automatic or do you have to make Matlab somehow aware of your GPU?

Comment: @Jonas Though I am not fully aware of the interval workings of `pagegun` and neither of `arrayfun`, but `arrayfun` appears to be using loops too inside (at least this much I know). So, doesn't that make both `pagefun` and `arrayfun` equivalent in using `loops` inside their implementations, with that one difference that `pagefun` works on GPUs ? Or by that "good way of pushing", you mean there is some sort of GPU optimization involved in it?

Comment: @Divakar: sorry, "good" may not have been the most appropriate term. I meant it in the sense of "a way that makes things actually run on the GPU". Pagefun is most likely more optimized and consequently limited to certain functions only.

Comment: @Dan: you need to define the arrays as gpuArrays, for which you need the parallell computing toolbox.